# How can I reference a contact's Drupal/Wordpress/Joomla account with a CiviMail token?

Tags: civimail, wordpress, drupal, joomla, tokens

From time to time we need to send messages through CiviMail that include a contact's CMS (Drupal/Wordpress/Joomla) username or ID. How can we add this to the available tokens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1: Use the CiviToken extension [recommended, CMS independent]**: 
Fuzion's [CiviToken](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.civitoken) extension provides `{user.name}` and `{user.id}` tokens by default. (*Pro tip:* this module also makes it easy to add custom tokens in a *tokens/* folder in your CiviCRM custom PHP directory; you can duplicate and modify a file from the *tokens/* folder in this extension)

**Option 2: Custom token in your own Drupal module [Drupal specific]**: 
[Coleman](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/users/4/coleman) authored a blog post some years back which outlined [how to make custom tokens](https://civicrm.org/blogs/colemanw/create-your-own-tokens-fun-and-profit). The following snippet is based on that and when slipped into a custom module will make the Drupal username available as a token in CiviMail.

```
<?php
/* CiviCRM token addition for Drupal username */

function MYMODULE_civicrm_tokens(&$tokens) {
  $tokens['username'] = array(
    'username.drupal' => 'Drupal username',
  );
}

function MYMODULE_civicrm_tokenValues(&$values, $cids, $job = null, $tokens = array(), $context = null) {
  // Username tokens
  if (!empty($tokens['username'])) {

    civicrm_initialize();
    foreach ($cids as $cid) {
      $params = array(
        'version' => 3,
        'sequential' => 1,
        'contact_id' => $cid,
      );
      $result = civicrm_api('UFMatch', 'get', $params);
      if (!$result['is_error']) {
        $drupalinfo = user_load($result['values'][0]['uf_id']);
        $values[$cid]['username.drupal'] = $drupalinfo->name;
      }
    }

  }
}
?>
```

Keep in mind that this is the bare bones and doesn't include any handling of a contact without a Drupal account. (So you would want to make sure to only use this token when sending to contacts with a Drupal account.)

Comment: nice example :)

Comment: Even better than avoiding non-users, you could just have an "else" that returns something innocuously generic or suggests that the recipient create an account.

Comment: I think it's better not to produce a value if there isn't one. People can then use Smarty to provide a default value foe non-user contacts if desired.