# Getting volunteer role in to email template

Tags: joomla, civivolunteer

We are using CiviVolunteer, and trying to setup a email template in that need to display volunteer role.  I think volunteer role is in activity record type. It does not show up in the token list in email template. I can get all the custom fields I have created in the volunteer signup profile.
Looking for a way to get volunteer role as token, please help

Thanks
Naheed

Answer (score 1):

If you need something in a token that isn't a default token, you may need to create a custom token. [Here's an earlier post with some example code](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/249/how-can-i-reference-a-contacts-drupal-account-from-civimail). (You would switch out the logic that searches for the Drupal username with some logic that pulls the Volunteer Role from CiviCRM and inserts it into the token.)